# Is it a good idea to pass a oven range hood exit duct in the roofs' ventilator?

Tags: roof, oven, range, hood

I've just had a oven range hood installed, but now I have to install the ducts for the air to exit my house.

My roof ventilator is pretty much right above where the oven is in my attic (its in quebec, its an unused attic, just for isolation)

So is it a good idea to run the ducts to the roof ventilator for the air exit, or its something that sounds good on paper, but is a terrible idea in practice?

PS: No idea if I'm using the right words since i'm french canadian, and so the terms i'm used to are different.

So here's what I mean by a oven range hood https://www.homedepot.com/b/Appliances-Range-Hoods/N-5yc1vZc3nk (in french we call it a 'hotte de four')

And here is what I mean by a roof ventilator https://www.rona.ca/en/ventilation-maximum-roof-ventilator-12-in-x-12-in-301-12-b-6467005 (mostly heard it referred to as a 'maximum')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like a bad idea. If it is sealed so that only air from the range hood goes through it you have eliminated an attic vent.

If it is just kinda pointed at the attic vent you will be introducing moist greasy air into the attic space.

Also the chance of a kitchen fire getting into the attic greatly increases with any option other than a termination cap designed for and exclusively used for range hood.

Use a smooth hard metal duct to connect the hood to the termination cap.

Answer (score 0):

I would not place any ducting inside your roof vent as it would reduce the capacity of its outlet.

The proper way would be to duct it up into the attic space, make a turn and go horizontal to the closest gable end of the attic, and out through the wall with a proper vent cap.

There are distance considerations related to duct size, turns and the CFM of the fan.